# dialog get html span value on click jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, modal-dialog

This is how i open the dialog box i found a tutorial long ago and i forgot the link to that tutorial

```
$("#dialog1").html("Mr. " + "<span id='name'>" + data[i].name + "</span>" + "has a building property in <span id='address'>" + data[i].address + "</span>");
$("#dialog1").dialog({title: pml});
$("#dialog1").dialog("open");
```

and this is how i create the dialog box

```
var div = $("<div id='dialog1'>");
    $("body").prepend(div);
    $("#dialog1").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        //title: "Modal",
        height: 250,
        width: 400,
        buttons: {
            "Add": function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            },
                "No": function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            },
        "close": function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
        }
    });
```

Currently the button `add and no` has function of closing the dialog box but i want to add a function in a way that when `add button(which is inside the dialog box) is clicked` i will get the value of the span in the `html of the dialog` so that i can use it as `parameter for ajax request`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply execute function in "Add" function:

```
...
"Add": function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
            somefunction($('#span_id').text());  // #span_id = id of span whitch you want to get text from
},
...
```

and

```
function somefunction(text) {
   // ajax call
}
```

Comment: i just want to know how to get the value of the span would directly calling the span id get the span text?

Comment: Like i wrote, use $(" #id or [name="your_name"] or .class ").text() to get text of selected container.